# Too many connections to datasource

Tags: mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

I have an application that I use BoneCP for connection pooling and when I deploy the war to tomcat, it works perfectly. But when I create another war (almost identical, just different skin and DB connection) ans deploy them both the I get the following error when tomcat starts up:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

Note that this does not happen after a period of time, so it is not that I am leaking connections by not closing them, but rather on startup.

My hibernate/boneCP connection properties in my spring config are as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${connection.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${connection.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${connection.password}</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAge">60</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod">5</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.partitionCount">3</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.acquireIncrement">10</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">60</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">20</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.statementsCacheSize">50</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.releaseHelperThreads">3</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
....
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How many connections can your mysql server handle ? run the query `show variables like 'max_connections';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/503370) thread:

> This is a sign that you have asked
>   BoneCP to create more connections then
>   your mysql server is configured to
>   accept. Either increase the number of
>   connections mysql will allow (via
>   mysql administrator) or tell bonecp to
>   create fewer connections.
>
> By default MySQL allows you to create
>   just a few connections so I would
>   start with that first.
>
> P.S. Sorry about the captcha test -
>   the amount of spambot attempts I get
>   hit with is unbelievable; I'm going to
>   turn it down a notch.

You either have to decrease `bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition`, or modify the configuration of your MySQL server to accept `60 * number of instances of your app` simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 3):

You created 3 partitions with a maximum of 60 connections each so you're hitting mysql with 180 connections there (the default in mysql is far lower than that).

Comment: ??? Please see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901508/what-are-the-maximum-concurrent-connections-to-a-mysql-database) It says "You'd probably run out of memory, file handles, and network sockets, on your server long before you got anywhere close to that limit."

Comment: The limit referred to above is the default.  On my machine in 2013 it was - show variables like 'max_connections'; 151.  So yes the maximum number is maximum range: 4,294,967,295  (e.g. 2**32 - 1) per the link you provided, but it is not the default value.