# 800 websites sharing same unique original database

Tags: mysql, database, multiple-sites

Is possible to have multiple websites (800 total) hosted in a dedicated server to connect and use the tables of a unique mysql database?

Answer (score 2):

It should work normally:
[Maximum concurrent connections to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901508/what-are-the-maximum-concurrent-connections-to-a-mysql-database)

> You'd probably run out of memory, file handles, and network sockets,
>   on your server long before you got anywhere close to that limit.

But keep in mind that you are using one MySQL Server which can have lower limits in the settings.

So you should be using caching solutions to lower the amound of requests.