# What is the execution flow of the following PHP script?

Tags: php, html, forms

These are the two files:

this_one.php

```
    <?php 

    include_once("other_one.php");

    $n1 = $_POST['name'];
    $n2 = $_POST['password'];

    echo "From this_one.php ".$n1." ".$n2."<br>";
    ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

other_one.php

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

echo "From other_one.php".$name." ".$pass."<br>";
?>
```

Now as I read somewhere if the form action is left empty the POST is sent to the script itself. Also other_one.php has been included in the file this_one.php

But when I run in the browser the output is:

```
From other_one.php hello pass
From this_one.php hello pass
```

How is everything working and why is this output received?

PS: Don't explain to me how `include_once` works. What I say is that for 10 processes the script would run from line 1 right upto the end, what if I was opening a connection to a database in the included file, this way I would be creating the same $connection instance 10 times, which would be an overhead. What would be a way to share a single database instance for all those 10 threads?

Comment: And what output didi you expect?

Comment: @u_mulder I expected undefined from the file other_one.php because POST went to this_one.php but now I understand everything. This means each time something happens the whole combined file gets executed, which is very costly for performance. If I was opening a database connection, instead of creating an instance once like JAVA and reusing it again and again, I would be creating a connection everytime once I include database.php. How do proffesionals get through this or am I missing something?

Comment: `include_once` and `require_once` will grab the file only once. If an include/require is attempted again on that file, it will skip it.

Comment: @aynber Yes I understand that, but suppose I have `include_once('database.php');` inside login.php and I do a POST, then it will execute the entire database.php alongwith login.php. If not why? Because as @chris-hass 's answer shows the whole file gets copied and is executed from the top to bottom, line by line

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton apologies, my comment was even less helpful. Wait, why noone yielding htmlentities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `include` directive brings the code in the specified file into scope. Mentally, you can just replace the include directive with the block of code inside of that file, there isn't really a difference. Knowing that, your code is effectively:

```php
    <?php 

    //include_once("other_one.php");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    echo "From other_one.php".$name." ".$pass."<br>";

    $n1 = $_POST['name'];
    $n2 = $_POST['password'];

    echo "From this_one.php ".$n1." ".$n2."<br>";
    ?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

*edit*

There are four directives for bringing code into the scope of the current process/request. Before I name them, please take note that I said current process/request. If 10 people hit your login page, you will have 10 processes/requests. Similarly, if 1 person hits your login page 10 times you will also have 10 processes/requests. This is the very nature of PHP and unless you actually notice a performance problem, I wouldn't worry about that.

The four directives are `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once`. The directives that end with `_once` guarantee that a provided file only ever gets brought into the process once. The other two directives allow a file to be included multiple times per process. The difference between `include` and `require` is subtle, but basically `include` will generate a ignorable warning if it can't find the file whereas `require` will throw a fatal error.

Generally I personally always recommend that you use `require_once` for all includes *unless* you explicitly have a reason to bring in code multiple times. For instance, if you have a pager widget that needs to live at the top and bottom of a table, that's a good use for including the same file multiple times. I never, ever use `include` or `include_once` because I can't imagine a scenario where a problem with including would be acceptable to me.

Also, as a side-note, [PHP resolves a file's path in a potentially surprising way](https://cjhaas.com/2019/05/21/php-include-path-surprises/). For instance, if you use `include 'file.php';` that actually *does not* mean include the file in the current directory. Instead, there's an optional "include path" that an administrator can set (for arguably legacy reasons, as far as I'm concerned), and using that syntax search the include path first. If you don't have an include path, or that file can't be found in that path, *then* the local folder is used. For that reason, I recommend always including files using "path semantics" which pretty much boils down to starting with a period or a forward slash, or a constant such as `__DIR__`.

Comment: I assume OPs code is silently throwing errors about those variables not existing before the form is submitted too

Comment: If I do `include_once('database.php');` inside login.php, each time I do a post a new instance of database would be created, which is a performance overhead. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kingmanas, I have updated my answer with more details that hopefully further answer your question

Comment: @ChrisHaas It still does not answer my question, what I say is that for 10 processes the script would run from line 1 to the end, what if I was opening a connection to a database in the included file, this way I would be creating the same $connection instance 10 times, which would be an overhead. What would be a way to share a single database instance for all those 10 threads?

Comment: There is probably technically overhead, but it is generally pretty minimal, to the point that it really isn't generally much of a concern, at least on some of the larger sites that I manage. MySQL [can handle about 4 billion simultaneous connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections). There are [connection pooling and persistent connection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) options for PHP and MySQL if you really want to set them up, but I would recommend waiting until you actually hit a perf problem

Comment: There is another thread on this site that goes deeper on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14901508/231316

Comment: @ChrisHaas I didn't really know about the 4 billion count, I really underestimated MySql